# How to declare Futures in Java without warnings?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

Trying to use Futures and IntelliJ is giving me various warnings, not sure how to code it 'correctly'.  The code works but obviously want to learn best practice.

```
try {
    public void  futuresTest() {
        try {
            List<String> valuesToProcess = List.of("A","B","C","D","E");
            
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
            List<Future<MyObject>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

            for(String s : valuesToProcess) {
                futures.add((Future<MyObject>) executor.submit(new MyObject(s)));     //<THIS
            }

            LOG.info("Waiting for threads to finish...");
            boolean termStatus = executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            
            if (termStatus) {
                LOG.info("Success!");
            } else {
                LOG.warn("Timed Out!");
                for(Future<MyObject> f : futures) {
                    if(!f.isDone()) {
                        LOG.warn("Failed to process {}:",f);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Gives `Unchecked cast: 'java.util.concurrent.Future<capture<?>>' to 'java.util.concurrent.Future<model.MyObject>'`

```
            List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();

            for(String s : valuesToProcess) {
                futures.add(  executor.submit(new MyObject(s)));
            }
```

Gives `Raw use of parameterized class 'Future'`

is it just supposed to be `List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();`  that has no warnings but I would think I should be specifying my Object.

Comment: This is going to depend on what exactly `MyObject` is.  A `MyObject` is probably _not_ a `Future<MyObject>` nor a `Callable<MyObject>`.

Comment: Since at no point do you need the type of the result of the Future, why not just declare `List<Future<?>> futures` ?

Comment: @LouisWasserman it's my own class that Implements Runnable.  
@ access violation let's say I do want to?

Comment: If your class implements `Runnable`, then it _has_ no result and no type, so @accessviolation's solution is correct.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - good point; not only is the result "not used", it's non-existent :-)

Comment: @LouisWasserman So I'm obviously missing a point here, I thought executor.submit returns a Future object that I can then check to see if it's done?  That's my goal here.  Ideally if I can at end of timeout go to each Future that isn't finished and get the MyObject back to reference what times out.

Comment: You're correct that it returns a Future object that you can check to see if it's done.  You cannot get back from that to a MyObject, and the Future you receive won't have any meaningful data in it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so basically I should be using `Future<?>`  --- what would be the proper way to do this that I can inspect the timed out MyObject?   (Thanks)

Comment: Interestingly there is sort of internal reference, when for each `Future` I print it to log the output contains `<LOG MESSAGE> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@5c4b1094[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@6aef552f[Wrapped task = MyObject{<myObjectToString.....`

Comment: Instead of a list of futures, you could keep a map of futures to the associated objects.

Comment: Yes, and that's normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments it does sound  like the correct approach is

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for(String s : valuesToProcess) {
    futures.add(executor.submit(new MyObject(s)));
}
```